# Backbone sync/save with MongoDB ObjectID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

One thing I don't understand about Backbone is how it knows which objects in the database to sync with. I am using MongoDB on the backend - how do I tell Backbone to generate MongoDB style ObjectIDs to store in the DB (perhaps Backbone just gets the IDs from Mongo - but if not how do I guarantee this Backbone generated IDs are unique in comparison to the MongoDB generate ObjectIDs?) The main problem I am having is that no Backbone.Model id is appended to the end of the root url I define in my Model upon a PUT or DELETE call.

here is my model:

```
var team = document.getElementsByName('team');
console.log(team);

var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        ID: "",
        team: team,
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        age: '',
        phone: '',
        email: ''
    },
    idAttribute: "ID",
    urlRoot: 'http://localhost:3000/api/players'
});

var PlayerCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Player
});
```

here is the view:

```
var addPlayerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    id: 'addPlayerDiv',
    events: {
        'click #submitNewPlayer': 'onAddPlayer',
        'click #cancelNewPlayer': 'cancelAddPlayer'
    },
    initialize: function () {

    },
    render: function () {
        var playerTemplate = document.getElementById('add-player-template').innerHTML;
        this.$el.html(_.template(playerTemplate)());
        return this;
    },
    onAddPlayer: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = form2js('add-player-template-form','.',true);
        this.model.set({id:data.age,age:data.age,phone:data.phone,email:data.email});
        this.model.save();
        $(this.el).removeData();
        this.unbind();
        this.remove();
        window.mainManageRosterView.render();
    }

});
```

and here is where I initialize a new view with a new model instance:

```
<script>

    function addNewPlayer(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var player = new Player({}); //perhaps this is incorrect, the id is null/undefined after all
        var newPlayerView = new addPlayerView({el: $("#addPlayerDiv"), model: player});
        var rendered = newPlayerView.render();
        $(rendered.el).appendTo(this.$el).hide().fadeIn().slideDown();
    };

</script>
```

Surely I am doing something wrong. The model is definitely not undefined in the view, but it has no ID. How do I give my Backbone model an ID? Perhaps Backbone only gives the model an id after it is saved?

To reiterate, the main problem I am having is that Backbone is not automatically appending an ID to the end of the root URL that I defined above in the model:

```
PUT /api/players/ 404 319ms - 475b
```

but it should look like this:

```
PUT /api/players/[mongoDB ObjectID here] 200 319ms - 475b
```

so basically, the ID is missing, and I don't know why. Furthermore, why the hell is Backbone doing a PUT? Shouldn't it being a POST if it's the first time it's saving this model?

Comment: `this.model.set({id:data.age,age:data.age,phone:data.phone,email:data.email});` try capital letters for `id` as you define in `idAttribute`

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible, that the `ID` is not defined, because you just define the `id`?

You are using `this.model.set({id:data.age, ...` (**lowercase**) to define your identifier.
But defined `idAttribute: "ID",` (**uppercase**) as ID Attribute.